# Can we get click/open details from emails being deployed from Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, journeybuilder

We have set of journey emails which will be deploying based on subscriber activity. But we have to get complete journey subscriber activity details in one Data Extension. Is it possible to get it by using Query?

Comment: Do you want a list of all opens, clicks, etc in one data extension?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can get the complete journey subscriber activity details in one Data Extension by writing queries on system data views.

SFMS provides data views like `_Sent`, `_Open`, `_Click`, `_JourneyActivity`, `_Journey`, `_Subscribers`. You can join all these data views to get the required data into our data extension.

Here are a few examples for you.

- [Query Journey Builder Sends in the Last 24 hours](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/query_journey_builder_sends_in_last_24_hours/)
- [Query Journey Builder Sends by Email Across Versions](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/query_journey_builder_sends_by_email_across_versions/)
- [Query Journey Builder Bounced Email Messages](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/query_journey_builder_bounced_email_messages/)